# Get fast resultset with mysql jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have a lineitem table with 6001215 rows of data and I wanted to get the result of this query `SELECT * FROM LINEITEM` quickly, to then treat the data from the resultset in memory.
I have this code, but it's still very slow anyway.

```
           String Query = "SELECT * FROM LINEITEM";
           Properties p = new Properties();
           p.setProperty("user", "root");
           p.setProperty("password", "root");
           p.setProperty("MaxPooledStatements", "10000");
           p.setProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
           p.setProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tpch",p);
           conn.setAutoCommit(false);
           PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
           resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(Query);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
       }
```

Comment: You really want to pull 6 million rows into memory? Where do you actually process the resultset

Comment: You should call `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` instead of `preparedStatement.executeQuery(Query)`.

Comment: I need to have the resultset all results for later use. Is there another way apart from being in memory?

Comment: Well it really depends upon what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to fetch the hashcode from each line and save it

Comment: You may want to look into something like hibernate which knows how to optimize the data transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to make the database connection before the query run, making the connection in a method can reduce the performance when you will call that method again and again it will create db connection each time and use preparedStatement.executeQuery(); instead of preparedStatement.executeQuery(Query);

Use a POJO class implementation in order to save the Resulset fetched from the database table into a list of entities and then retrieve the column values whenever you want.